# Angular Material Table Sorting using a reactive formarray

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular 11

I cannot see where my issue is here.  I have a simple mat-table using a react form.  Everything works except the sorting.  I only want the user to be able to sort on three fields - TimeOff, RestoreTime and Customers.  I have reviewed over a dozen similar articles on StackOverflow but can't seem to pinpoint the issue.  Anyone have any thoughts?  I have included a StackBlitz below.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-d2pmtb?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-app.module.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-app.component.ts,tsconfig.json,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-app.component.html&title=Angular%20Starter)